# Zend_Form form-tag class

Tags: css, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

i would like to add a class to the Zend-Form form-tag:

```
<form class="myClass" ..> ... </form>
```

How can i do that? My friend Google wont help me :(

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple of ways...

In the constructor

```
$form = new Zend_Form(array(
    'class' => 'myClass'
));
```

or using the `Zend_Form::setAttrib()` method

```
$form->setAttrib('class', 'myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

> setAttrib('class', 'myClass');

`Zend_Form::setAttrib()` is no longer available, use `Form::setAttribute()` instead.